# use naturality to show bimodule homomorphism

Tags: modules, natural-transformations

Let $A, B$ be $k$-algebras, and let $M, M'$ be $A-B$-bimodules.

There is a bijection $Nat(Hom_A(M, −), Hom_A(M', −)) \cong
Hom_{A⊗_kB^{op}} (M', M)$ sending a natural transformation $η : Hom_A(M, −) \to Hom_A(M', −)$ to $η(M)(Id_M)$.

In the proof, the author states that One needs to make use of the naturality of $η$ with respect to the right $B$-module structures on $M, M'$ to show that the map $η(M)(Id_M)$ is a bimodule homomorphism. This confused me as I cannot see the connection between naturality and being a bimodule homomorphism.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks like an application of Yoneda. But I'd expect $\text{Hom}_A(M',M)$ on the right.

Comment: Yes, it is a special case

Comment: at least the author states so.

Comment: second part is about natural isomorphisim between tensors.. The right side is still a bimodule homo space. I just don't get what he meant by using naturality. Been thinking about this for a while...

Comment: By definition, $\eta_M({\rm id}_M)$ is an $A$-module morphism only. I bet you need to use naturality somehow on the $A$-morphism $m\mapsto mb$.

Comment: I tried, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key implicit information here is to consider both functors $\hom_A(M,-)$ and $\hom_A(M',-)$ as ${}_A{\bf Mod}\to {}_B{\bf Mod}$ (instead of the codomain being ${\bf Set}$ or ${}_k{\bf Vct}$), and thus assume that each component of $\eta$ is actually a *$B$-module morphism*.

If $M$ is an $A$-$B$-bimodule, we naturally get a *left* $B$-module structure on $\hom_A(M,N)$ for any ${}_AN$:
specifically we define $b\cdot f:=x\mapsto f(xb)$, i.e. we precompose $f$ by the map $(\cdot b):\underset{x\,\mapsto\, xb}{M\to M}\,$.

Now name $\,\varphi:=\eta_M({\rm id}_M)\in\hom_A(M',M)$. We need to show that it's also a right $B$-module morphism.

On the one hand, use the above assumption:
$$\eta_M((\cdot b))\ =\ \eta_M(b\cdot {\rm id}_M)\ =\ b\cdot\eta_M({\rm id}_M)\ =\ b\cdot \varphi\ =\ m'\mapsto\varphi(m'b)$$
On the other hand, indeed use naturality of $\eta$ along the $A$-module morphism $(\cdot b):M\to M$, here we have postcomposition by it:
$$\matrix{ \hom_A(M,M) & \overset{\eta_M}\longrightarrow & \hom_A(M',M) \\
{\scriptstyle (\cdot b)\circ}\Big\downarrow\phantom{\scriptstyle (\cdot b)\circ} &&
\phantom{\scriptstyle (\cdot b)\circ}\Big\downarrow {\scriptstyle (\cdot b)\circ} \\
\hom_A(M,M) & \underset{\eta_M}\longrightarrow & \hom_A(M',M) }$$
to obtain $\eta_M((\cdot b))\ =\ m'\mapsto \varphi(m')b$.